# EF Switch between different contexts of same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a mulitenant application, which has multiple databases for different customers having same db structure.

In application, after user logs in based on his customer-id I will know connection string for his customer database and after his login button click event I will need to change my db context dynamically on the fly.

I am using EF 5.0 and Autofac IOC container.
I have pasted my code here which is not helping me.

Whats the best way I can manage this?

```
        string EntityFrameworkConnectionString = null;
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntityFrameworkConnectionString))
            {
                var profileProvider = c.Resolve<IConfigurationProfileProvider<CustomerProfile>>();
                var profile = profileProvider.GetProfile();
                EntityFrameworkConnectionString = profile.CustomerDatabaseConnectionString;
            }
            return new CustomerDataContext(EntityFrameworkConnectionString);
        })
        .As<ICustomerDataContext>()
        .As<IDbContext>()
        .InstancePerDependency();

        builder.RegisterType<CustomerDataContextFactory>().As<ICustomerDataContextFactory>();

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: Why do you leave EntityFrameworkConnectionString variable outside of the registration delegate? It's bad because of closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that like this:

1. Introduce an interface that will manage the connection strings:

   ```
   public interface IConnectionStringManager
   {
       string GetConnectionString();
   }
   ```
2. With the implementation that has IConfigurationProfileProvider injected into it:

   ```
   public class ConnectionStringManager : IConnectionStringManager
   {
       private readonly IConfigurationProfileProvider<CustomerProfile> _configurationProfileProvider;

       public ConnectionStringManager(IConfigurationProfileProvider<CustomerProfile> configurationProfileProvider)
       {
           _configurationProfileProvider = configurationProfileProvider;
       }

       public string GetConnectionString()
       {
           return _configurationProfileProvider.GetProfile().CustomerDatabaseConnectionString;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then inject IConnectionStringManager into CustomerDataContext and get the connection string.

   ```
   public CustomerDataContext(IConnectionStringManager connectionStringManager)
   {
       var connectionString = connectionStringManager.GetConnectionString();
       // pass the connectionString to your context
   }
   ```
4. And register ConnectionStringManager and CustomerDataContext as usual:

   ```
   builder.RegisterType<ConnectionStringManager>().As<IConnectionStringManager>();
   builder.RegisterType<CustomerDataContext>()
       .As<ICustomerDataContext>()
       .As<IDbContext>()
       .InstancePerDependency();
   ```

BTW, Take a look at the [Autofac Multitenant Integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MultitenantIntegration) which could ease multitenant support.

Comment: Thanks Alexandr! Can you show me how I can do step-3 with some code?

Comment: Also, in my application after user logs in based on his customer-id I will know connection string for his customer database. So, do I need to do these 4 steps after his login button click event? and will that change my db context dynamically on the fly?

Comment: @rajcool111 Regarding step 3, it depends on your CustomerDataContext implementation. I would go with constructor injection, something like "public CustomerDataContext(IConnectionStringManager connectionStringManager) { var connectionString = connectionStringManager.GetConnectionString();}". Also I updated the answer.

Comment: @rajcool111 "So, do I need to do these 4 steps after his login button click event? and will that change my db context dynamically on the fly?" you need to do it in place where you configure your container. Yes, it should change your db context dynamically (on next resolve of the context), depends on your implementation of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you would need to use your IOC for this case (especially considering how complicated you've made it). Why not just store that connection string as a static variable, and then override your `DbContext`'s constructor to always use that variable?

Like so:

For the connection string:

```
public static class StaticVariables
{
  public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

For your `DbContext` constructor:

```
public DbContext()
{
  this(StaticVariables.ConnectionString);
}
```

Comment: That would be a disaster in a concurrent environment.